# split one line regex in a multiline regexp in perl

Tags: regex, perl, inline, multiline

I have trouble spliting my regex in multiple line. I want my regex to match the line given:

```
* Code "l;k""dfsakd;.*[])_lkaDald"
```

So I created this regex which work:

```
my $firstRegexpr = qr/^\s*\*\s*Code\s+\"(?<Code>((\")*[^\"]+)+)\"/x;
```

But now I want to split it in multiline like this(and want it to match the same thing!):

```
my $firstRegexpr = qr/^\s*\*\s*Code\s+\"
(?<Code>((\")*[^\"]+)+)\"/x;
```

I read about this, but I have trouble using it:

```
/
 ^\s*\*\s*Code\s+\"
 (?<Code>((\")*[^\"]+)+)\"
/x
```

My last question is about removing inlining variable in perl regex:

```
 my $firstRegexpr = qr/^\s*\*\s*Code\s+\"(?<Code>((\")*[^\"$]+)+)\"\$/x;
```

the character **$]** is matched as a variable in the regex, how to define it not as a variable?

**Thanks a lot for your time** and please provide explicit example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the `x` flag does is very simply say 'ignore whitespace'.

So you no longer match 'space' characters , and instead *have* to use `\s` or similar.

So you can write:

```
if ( m/
        ^
        \d+\s+
        fish:\w+\s+
        $ 
      /x ) {
    print "Matched\n";
}
```

You can test regular expressions with various websites but one example is https://regex101.com/

So to take your example: https://regex101.com/r/eG5jY8/1

But how is yours not working?

This matches:

```
my $string = q{* Code "l;k""dfsakd;.*[])_lkaDald"};

my $firstRegexpr = qr/^\s*
                        \*
                       \s*
                       Code\s+
                       \"
                       (?<Code>((\")*[^\"]+)+)
                       \"
                    /x;

print "Compiled_Regex: $firstRegexpr\n";
print "Matched\n" if ( $string =~ m/$firstRegexpr/ );
```

And as for not having `$]` - there's two answers. Either: Use `\` to escape it, or use `\Q\E`.

Comment: Can you still give me an example with \Q\E with the current regex
 my $firstRegexpr = qr/^\s*\*\s*Code\s+\"(?<Code>((\")*[^\"$]+)+)\"\$/x;
 , it didn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `\Q$\E]` I think should do it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to do it like this: \Q$]\E, and this doesn't work. using your way : \Q$\E] it work. :)

Comment: If you put it inside the `\E` then it 'escapes' it and stops treating it as a closing bracket.